# Why do some text has different height on android?

Tags: android, firefox, fonts

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 and S22 Ultra. Both have the same firefox, still the result is slightly different:

[image]

with S10 its fine, appears just like it supposed to be. But with S22 its a bit different, its bigger. It happens to other parts of the site. What can be wrong? The font sizes are directly sized, with `px`.

[www.normalnonoobs.com](http://www.normalnonoobs.com) btw

Comment: System font scaling is controllable from the Settings app. Mozilla Fennec also has a few other options for font scaling in its Accessibility menu -- Firefox might offer the same.

Answer (score 1):

Cause different devices have different PPI (pixel per inch).

> One device might have 160 pixels per inch, while another device fits
> 480 pixels in the same space.

And that web page is not using density-independent units like DP in Android native apps.

Comment: Last I knew, `px` in CSS is density-independent, akin to `dp` on Android.

Comment: Why then Emulator the web page looked good as on s10? I installed Firefox and the emulator resolution was the same as s22

Comment: I thought px is independent... then what to use?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on an Android emulator and I couldn't get the same result as you
[image]

emulator settings
[image]

Double check settings on your phone

Comment: Thats right, but I dont even know what settings I must look into. And why dont other websites have this problem?

Comment: Try to go Settings -> Accessibility -> Automatic font sizing. By making the font size bigger I managed to get the same result as S22